# It shows more items in array than expected

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

It shows more times than expected and when I add 1 item and it is stackable it adds to stack....but not once 2 times.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ArenaRPG
{
    public class Inventory
    {

        int slotWight;
        int slotHeight;
        int ItemsPerpage = 1;
        int CurrentPage;
        int Columns, Rows;

        B_Item[,] items;

        Backpack backpack;
        Vector2 pos;

        public Inventory(Backpack bpack,int itemsPerPage,int Columns,int Rows,  int SlotWidth, int SlotHeight, Vector2 Pos)
        {
            this.backpack = bpack;
            this.slotHeight = SlotHeight;
            this.slotWight = SlotWidth;
            this.pos = Pos;
            this.Columns = Columns;
            this.ItemsPerpage = itemsPerPage;
            this.Rows = Rows;
           items = new B_Item[Columns, Rows];
            LoadItems(bpack);                
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            double Maxpages = Math.Ceiling((double)(items.Length - 1) / ItemsPerpage);

            if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.A))
            {
                CurrentPage++;
            }

            if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.D))
            {
                CurrentPage--;
            }

            Input.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            var result = items.Cast<B_Item>().Skip(ItemsPerpage * (CurrentPage-1)).Take(ItemsPerpage);
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                for (int X = 0; X < Columns; X++)
                {
                    for (int Y = 0; Y < Rows; Y++)
                    {
                        int DrawX = (int)pos.X + (X * (slotWight + 2));
                        int DrawY = (int)pos.Y + (Y * (slotWight + 2));

                        if(items[X,Y] != null)
                        {
                            spriteBatch.Draw(item.Texure, new Rectangle(DrawX, DrawY ,32, 32), new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64), Color.White);
                            if (items[X,Y].StackSize > 1)
                            {
```

spriteBatch.DrawString(AssetManager.GetInstance().font["Arial8"], items[X,Y].StackSize.ToString(), new Vector2(DrawX+ 20, DrawY+20), Color.DarkBlue);
                                }
                                spriteBatch.DrawString(AssetManager.GetInstance().font["Arial8"], CurrentPage.ToString(), new Vector2(50, 50), Color.DarkBlue);
                            }

```
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void LoadItems(Backpack BPack)
        {
            int itemIndex = 0;

            for (int X = 0; X < Columns; X++)
            {
                for (int Y = 0; Y < Rows; Y++)
                {
                    if (itemIndex < BPack.items.Count)
                    {
                        items[X, Y] = BPack.items[itemIndex];
                        itemIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Backpack is simple

```
public void AddItems(B_Item NewItem)
{
    if (items.Count < MaxSlots)
    {
        foreach (var i in items.ToArray())
        {
            if (i.Item_Name == NewItem.Item_Name )
            {
                if (i.Is_Stackable == true && i.StackSize < 500)
                {
                    i.StackSize += 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                items.Add(NewItem);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        items.Add(NewItem);
    }                   
}

private void Remove(B_Item itemID)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            items[i].StackSize -= 1;
        }

            items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Why does draw more items than specified by value `itemsPerPage` in inventory.
constructor

```
Inventory thiss = new Inventory(new PlayerBack(),2,1,32,32, 32, new Vector2(0, 0))
```

Comment: You add same item 2 times, delete `items.Add(NewItem)` at the end of `AddItems` method.

Comment: Deleted 2nd items.Add(NewItem) now it does not show any items to a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, sorry for comment it's abit wrong. Here correct method:

```
public void AddItems(B_Item NewItem)
        {
            if (items.Count < MaxSlots)
            {
                foreach (var i in items.ToArray())
                {
                    if (i.Item_Name == NewItem.Item_Name )
                    {
                        if (i.Is_Stackable == true && i.StackSize < 500)
                        {
                            i.StackSize += 1;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            items.Add(NewItem);

        }
```